# Trying to checkin on Facebook through ShareLinkContent using FBSDKSharekit pod version 14.1.0 but no luck

Tags: facebook, swift5, checkin, fbsdksharekit, fbsdksharedialog

I'm trying to add checkin functionality on my app. I got the place Id from admin panel and If user wants to checkin their they can do that through my app using the code below, but for some reason this code is not working only posting the link without taking the location, even this code can post quote as well but no location.
PS: The Facebook app is in development mode and the place id is valid as the same place id is working on android.

```
    let content : ShareLinkContent = ShareLinkContent()
            content.contentURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
            content.placeID = "493869400814446"
            let dialog = ShareDialog(
                viewController: self,
                content: content,
                delegate: nil
            )
            dialog.mode = .automatic
            dialog.show()
```